# How to access the database in Helper Functions in CI4

Tags: codeigniter, codeigniter-3, codeigniter-4

CI4: I have created database object in Controller, i want to execute helper function which has some queries,

Question: How to access the database in Helper Functions in CI4?

Comment: Is there a reason you're not creating Models? This is the entire point of them.

Comment: I have created model, some of the operations which used most of the times on entire app, so i need to execute the database query in helper functions and return some result.

Answer (score 1):

you can use by adding these lines in your helper function

```
$db = db_connect();

$result = $db->query("SELECT * FROM table")->getResult();
```

Answer (score 0):

You can access the builder from the model.

```
$model = new SomeModel();
$builder = $model->builder();
$builder->db  //returns the db conn used in model
```